# Understanding Cartheodory's Extension Theorem for probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to understand the technical necessity of Cartheodory's Extension Theorem from the [MIT OCW notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec02.pdf). I have only learned it at a basic level (no measure theory background) to justify extending a probability measure, so the motivation, as I understand it, is:

- We cannot easily define a probability measure for all subsets of a sigma-algebra.
- Instead, we define a field that generates the sigma-algebra we're interested in, with all the subsets we're interested in defining a probability for, and not necessarily the countable unions of those sets.
- We define the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on this field, which is easier because we only have finite unions of sets, so we can simply add the measure for each of the sets in the union.
- By Cartheodory's Extension Theorem, we can then claim that $\mathbb{P}$ is defined on the sigma-algebra generated by the field that we were originally interested in.

My questions:
(1) Why is it difficult to define a probability measure on the sigma-algebra? Why couldn't we have started off by assigning the probability measure we ended up with, $\mathbb{P}$, to subsets of the sigma-algebra without having to derive it from the field first?
(2) Why is it easier to define a probability measure on the field rather than the sigma-algebra (is my reasoning in the third step above correct?)
(3) Is $\mathbb{P}$ defined also on those sets in the sigma-algebra that were not in the field? If so, how is it defined if we constructed the probability measure for finite sets only (and again, why couldn't we have just defined it on the sigma-algebra directly)? If not, what is the probability of those sets? We can't simply have subsets in the sigma-algebra associated with a probability space without a probability, right?

Thanks in advance! Please correct any conceptual misunderstandings associated with the questions I have.

Comment: It would be best if you cite a textbook or an online source where your understanding of the Caratheodory Extension Theorem comes from.